# How to add a vertical line on the end of the chart.js scatter graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is how options for my chart look like

```
options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: "time",
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 15
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            padding: 22,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
            stepSize: 1
          },
          position: "left",
          gridLines: {
            drawTicks: false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

as you can see there is an option

```
gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
```

because of this there is no vertical lines on the chart.

What I want to do is to add only one vertical line on the end of the chart(right side of the chart)
Here is my live example https://codesandbox.io/s/line-chart-with-vanilla-js-and-chartjs-pi9fn?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved as follows:

Define `data.labels` in the chart configuration. Given your data, this could be done by extracting the `x` values of of the `data` objects using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const labels = data.map(o => o.x);
```

Then you need to adapt `xAxis.ticks` in order to instruct Chart.js that `ticks` (including grid lines) have to be generated  from user given `labels` (see [Tick Source](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source) from Chart.js documentation).

```
ticks: {
  source: 'labels'            
}
```

Further you have to change the definition of `xAxis.gridLines`. Make them displayed again and define `lineWidth` instead. This should be an `array` of `numbers` that specify the stroke width of individual grid lines. Basically all `0` except `1` for the last `number`.

```
gridLines: {
  lineWidth: labels.map((l, i) => i < labels.length - 1 ? 0 : 1)
}
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const data = [
  { x: "1-01", y: 1 },
  { x: "1-07", y: 3 },
  { x: "1-14", y: 2 },
  { x: "1-21", y: 4 },
  { x: "1-28", y: 5 },
  { x: "2-04", y: 1 }
];
const labels = data.map(o => o.x);

new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: "scatter",
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: data,
        label: "A",
        showLine: true,
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 4,
        pointRadius: 5,
        tension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        borderColor: "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: 'time',
          unit: 'day',
          time: {
            parser: 'M-D'
          },
          gridLines: {
            lineWidth: labels.map((l, i) => i < labels.length - 1 ? 0 : 1)
          },
          ticks: {
            source: 'labels',
            padding: 15            
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            padding: 22,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
            stepSize: 1
          },
          position: "left",
          gridLines: {
            drawTicks: false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks :)